# Grails / IntelliJ: trouble with simple groovy import?

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm following Burt Beckwith's (Grails developer and author) use of Heroku as indicated [here in Grails book](http://books.google.com/books?id=nLqyHl_KfTQC&pg=PA277&lpg=PA277&dq=error%20grails.plugin.heroku.PostgresqlServiceInfo&source=bl&ots=UAx3wTQJQ_&sig=aleGx0cDcAjBPQfPpUDZH89ixm0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DbUNUuiMK4iTyQGOn4GgBg&ved=0CGAQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=error%20grails.plugin.heroku.PostgresqlServiceInfo&f=false). (See import statement at top of this link -- that's what's giving me problems).

I added the following to BuildConfig.groovy as Burt indicates:

```
  runtime 'postgresql:postgresql:8.4-702.jdbc3'  // in the dependencies section as described

  compile ':heroku:1.0.1'  // in the plugins section as described.
```

Then IntelliJ prompted me to update the IDE with the BuildConfig changes, which I did.  I also exited and restarted IntelliJ to see if that might get rid of the import error for:

```
 import grails.plugin.heroku.PostgresqlServiceInfo
```

It did not get rid of the import error, which then complains when I do the addition of:

```
 PostgresqlServiceInfo info = new PostgresqlServiceInfo()
```

in the Bootstrap class as is shown in the example.  What am I doing wrong / how do I fix this kind of stuff?

Comment: Just for kicks, `cd` into the base app directory from the command line. Then run `grails clean` followed by `grails compile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IDEA you need to open `Tools` | `Grails` | `Plugins`, select **Heroku** plug-in and click **Apply Changes**.

This will configure a module for the plug-ins and add this module to the dependencies of your application.

Comment: I have requested that a bug be issued against IntelliJ for not properly warning that when it does "Update Changes" on BuildConfig.groovy it actually does not update the plugins -- and as such it is misleading and deficient.  It needs to at least tell the user that it does not update plugins and what the user needs to do to actually have the entries in BuildConfig.groovy mean something.

Answer (score 1):

- Take some time.
- Halt the idea of using IDEA for a moment.
- Use command prompt.
- Try the same steps.
- You will see everything working.

Works for me. :-)